# NGCC failed error in Angular 11.x app when running npm run

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-start

I have an Angular 11.x app that I run using `npm run start` - this has worked fine for months but all of a sudden it is no longer running the command and I am getting the following errors, can anyone suggest how I fix this? I have tried the obvious ideas of deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling them using `npm install` but with no joy.

Below is the error I get after running `npm run start` - what have I done to break this :(

```
Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
Error: Error on worker #1: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at injectDependencies (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:6960:21)
    at compileFactoryFunction (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:6888:61)
    at Object.compileInjector (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:8106:22)
    at NgModuleDecoratorHandler.compileFull (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/annotations/src/ng_module.js:427:44)
    at _loop_2 (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/transform/src/compilation.js:595:39)
    at NgccTraitCompiler.TraitCompiler.compile (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/transform/src/compilation.js:626:21)
    at DecorationAnalyzer.compileFile (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/analysis/decoration_analyzer.js:225:53)
    at DecorationAnalyzer.analyzeProgram (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/analysis/decoration_analyzer.js:164:45)
    at Transformer.analyzeProgram (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/packages/transformer.js:135:57)
    at Transformer.transform (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/packages/transformer.js:77:27)
    at ClusterMaster.onWorkerMessage (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/master.js:195:27)
    at /Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/master.js:55:95
    at ClusterMaster.<anonymous> (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/master.js:293:57)
    at step (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
    at /Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:117:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:113:16)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/master.js:287:32)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed.
See "/private/var/folders/b2/1zfdxz293d944p_lxk9_ypz40000gn/T/ng-XQcM3b/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

The error in the `angular-errors.log` file is as follows -

```
[error] Error: NGCC failed.
    at NgccProcessor.process (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ngcc_processor.js:129:19)
    at /Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:593:31
    at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10$
    at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Object.webpack [as webpackFactory] (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:55:30)
    at createWebpack (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-webpack/src/webpack-dev-server/index.js:21:36)
    at Object.runWebpackDevServer (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-webpack/src/webpack-dev-server/index.js:47:12)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.project (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/dev-server/index.js:209:32)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/swit$
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subs$
    at /Users/zabius/Sites/abc-ui-ng4/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeToPromise.js:7:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Versions :

```
npm -v 8.1.0
node -v 14.15.4
Using MacOS BigSur 11.5.2
```

Comment: I have had this same issue, did you ever solve it? I looked already at Ivy and compiler...